# R create Random Networks according data frame

Tags: r, loops, random, social-networking, igraph

I have a data frame `"ref.df"` that has info about 12 networks. I want to create 100 random networks for each subject according their node and edge numbers.

I've tried this code but it didn't work well:

```
    library(igraph)

    random.networks <- list()

    for(i in ref.df$subject){
              cat("...")
              for( j in 1:100){
              random.networks[[j]] <- sample_gnm(n=ref.df$node,m=ref.df$edge, directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
              }
              cat(i,"\n")
            }
```

This code generate 100 random networks only for the first subject.

Thanks for your time and advice in advance.

You can reproduce my data frame:

```
ref.df <- data.frame(subject=c("Civil.Liberties","Foreign.Policy","Women.s.Rights","Workers..Rights",
                           "Political.Polarisation","Kurdish.Peace.Process","Parallel.State",
                           "HDP.Election.Slogans","Related.With.Election","CHP.Election.Slogans",
                           "AKP.Election.Slogans","MHP.Election.Slogans"),
                 group=c(298,1150,474,2522,0,2570,718,2736,0,1661,2175,1460),
                 mod=c(0.77,0.73,0.84,0.78,0,0.72,0.66,0.62,0,0.68,0.76,0.66),
                 node=c(13524,68792,21925,87094,195678,98008,28499,93024,201342,61539,91640,63035),
                 edge=c(18694,183932,27120,143032,710044,249267,108352,255615,579919,17590,3313147,213367))
```

Comment: your outer loop is re-writing the random.networks variable at each cycle. Beside that, it is not clear to me how you are supposed to "center" your random network for a specific node. The line you use is independent on the subject... Is it really so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is that you want 12 x 100 networks and you are only getting a list of 100, with a minimal modification to your code, you can do as follows:

```
random.networks <- list()
for (subj in ref.df$subject){
  cat("...")
  for (i in 1:100) {
    tmp <- sample_gnm(n=ref.df$node[ref.df$subject == subj],
                      m=ref.df$edge[ref.df$subject == subj], 
                      directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
    random.networks[[(length(random.networks) + 1)]] <- tmp
    names(random.networks)[length(random.networks)] <- paste(as.vector(subj), i, sep = "_")
  }
  cat(as.vector(subj),"\n")
}

random.networks
```

If you want to make sure that the random networks you generate are different, you may want trying the following approach, but because of the cross comparisons, this will be very slow.

```
random.networks <- list()
look.up <- list()

for (subj in ref.df$subject){
  cat("...")
  for (i in 1:100) {

    tmp <- NA
    # enforce uniqueness
    while(is.na(tmp)|
          as.character(tmp)[4] %in% look.up) {
      tmp <- sample_gnm(n=ref.df$node[ref.df$subject == subj],
                        m=ref.df$edge[ref.df$subject == subj], 
                        directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
    }
    random.networks[[(length(random.networks) + 1)]] <- tmp
    look.up[[(length(look.up) + 1)]] <- as.character(tmp)[4]
    names(random.networks)[length(random.networks)] <- paste(as.vector(subj), i, sep = "_")
  }
  cat(as.vector(subj),"\n")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your code is create 100 random networks for each subject but as you can see in the "ref.df" each subject has different node (n) and edge (m) numbers. This code create only 13524 nodes and 18694 edges network. It means that 1200 networks have same node and edge number. Thanks.

Comment: There are ways to enforce uniqueness of the output networks, I guess. Is that important?

Comment: I only need to fix "n=ref.df$node" and "m=ref.df$edge" for each subject. Is there a way to create a loop for it @Damiano Fantini

Comment: It's the only reason that I create these random networks.

Comment: Can you make an example of how to tailor your random network to a specific node?

Comment: library(igraph) / Civil.Liberties <- sample_gnm(n=13524,m=18694, directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE) / Related.With.Election <-sample_gnm(n=201342,m=579919, directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE) . This code creates a network that has same node and edge numbers with different connections for both networks.

Comment: Ok, that's clear now. I was unsure about what the n and m arguments meant. I updated the code

Comment: Sorry for a late reply but I run the script and it took a while. It gives error message and I need to understand its meaning. Warning messages:
1: In while (is.na(tmp) | as.character(tmp)[4] %in% look.up) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152909/discussion-between-damiano-fantini-and-eabanoz).